# How can I reclaim the partition's space from this shrunk volume?

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, partition

I've already reverted the CoreStorage volume. And I've resized my "Macintosh HD" volume (by dragging it) and want to increase the size of my "Yosemite" volume.

How do I reclaim the space (in grey) from the first partition.

[image]

Comment: not that it helps a lot, but just gave you some + points for nice question.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in Disk Utility, or even while running the OS in the active partition.

I normally backup the partition to an external HD, then restore to the Mac.
This is easier if you have another OS, but you should be able to do it from the Recovery mode.

Another option is to remove the HD, and do it on another Mac.

There may be 3rd party utilities which can move partition, but none I have used let you move the active partition.

Comment: Recovery mode doesn't seem to let me do it, albeit I'm still on the same drive. What about the command-line diskUtil?

Comment: You can't modify the active partition, from command line or otherwise. What is on `Macintosh HD`? Does this have an OS?

Comment: yes it has 10.9 on it. However, that 120GB volume is in the ~160GB partition I'm trying to shrink (the grey space in the screenshot). BTW, I can't move and resize it when booted into "Macintosh HD" either.